# Blochchain Smart Contract App

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, ether, ethereum-wallet-dapp, bitcoin

Actually Im working on a blockchain application based on smart contracts that allows to buy/sell properties and paying in cryptocurrency using Ethereum and Bitcoin.

I wonder I develop smart contract with Solidity (js) or Web3j(Java) ?

The front of the app will be with angular but I dont know what to use in back: Java or Java script ? What is easier and more workable.

And Thank you !

Comment: Hi there. Solidity is not Javascript, it's a smart contract language. Web3 is not a smart contract language. Also, your general request is aimed at eliciting opinions, which isn't what Stack Exchange is for. I'd recommend asking this sort of thing on Reddit: https://reddit.com/r/ethereum or https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev

Answer (score 0):

Depends of your proyect needs. But I recommend you Web3js instead of Web3j. In my opinion is more implemented and are more examples fors tests in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting confused.
Smart contracts are written in Solidity which also isn't JavaScript but is influenced by it. What Web3 is, is a bridge between the smart contract running on the EVM and your front-end application. Since you're using Angular I recommend going for Web3js in combination with Solidity. I would also highly recommend the use of the Truffle Framework.
A guide on how to start could be found [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/build-a-dapp-using-ethereum-and-angular-6-a404fbf3c08d).

Goodluck coding!

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder I develop smart contract with Solidity (js) or Web3j(Java) ?

You develop the smart contracts with Solidity. You will likely need to learn how to use [Truffle](https://trufflesuite.com/).

> The front of the app will be with angular but I dont know what to use in back: Java or Java script ? What is easier and more workable.

For the backend - an app where users will be exchanging real world assets for cryptocurrencies I would use Java because it's secure and widely adopted. You can (ofcourse) build in other languages. I would go with what you are most familiar with.